# How do I merge 2 separate lists in java based on index?

Tags: java

Say I have 2 lists.

I want to merge both list into 1 list(mergeList in code) and expected output is:
**[11.65148,48.2490,0 11.6515,48.2490,0 11.6516,48.2491,0 ].**

Please suggest.

```
    List<Double> latitudeList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> longitudeList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> mergeList= new ArrayList<Double>();
    longitudeList.add(11.65148);
    longitudeList.add(11.6515);
    longitudeList.add(11.6516);


    latitudeList.add(48.2490);
    latitudeList.add(48.2490);
    latitudeList.add(48.2491);
```

Comment: Do you want to merge lists based on index instead of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code below to have your lists merged and sorted.

```
    mergeList.addAll(latitudeList);
    mergeList.addAll(longitudeList);
    mergeList.sort(new Comparator<Double>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
            if(o1.doubleValue() < o2.doubleValue()){
                return -1;
            }else if(o1.doubleValue() > o2.doubleValue()){
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Now:

```
System.out.println(mergeList);
```

Prints out:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
```

**UPD:**

```
    if(longitudeList.size() != latitudeList.size()){
        throw new IllegalStateException("longitudeList and latitudeList have to be of the same size");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < longitudeList.size(); i++){
        mergeList.add(longitudeList.get(i));
        mergeList.add(latitudeList.get(i));
    }

    System.out.println(mergeList);
```

Will print out:

```
[11.65148, 48.249, 11.6515, 48.249, 11.6516, 48.2491]
```

**UPD 2:**

Better to override `toString()` method for your `mergeList` like it is shown below:

```
    List<Double> mergeList= new ArrayList<Double>(){
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 1; i <= size(); i++){
                stringBuilder.append(get(i - 1));
                if(i % 3 == 0){
                    stringBuilder.append(" ");
                }else{
                    stringBuilder.append(",");
                }
            }
            stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    };
```

Then just add hardcoded altitude when you build up merged list:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < longitudeList.size(); i++){
        mergeList.add(longitudeList.get(i));
        mergeList.add(latitudeList.get(i));
        mergeList.add(0d);
    }

    System.out.println(mergeList);
```

So the output would be:

```
11.65148,48.249,0.0 11.6515,48.249,0.0 11.6516,48.2491,0.0
```

Comment: Hi Alexey, Thanks for your quick help. But i cannot use compare. The actual lists with which i am working contain longitude and latitude values. So list1 has longitude values and list2 has latitude values. I need list3 with merged values as [ longitude,latitude,longitude,latitude,...etc]. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I gave you the answer that solves the issue stated in your example. Rework your example.

Comment: I have updated the example. You can take a look now.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Hi Alexey. I have updated the expected a little. Can you please suggest how can i get such output?

Comment: I'm not getting the rule you use to build such the output. If you explain the logic, I'll try to suggest the solution.

Comment: Sure. I need to convert a Json response to Kml file which i can open in google earth. So the coordinates format for a KML file is: <coordinates>11.651548147201538,48.249088525772095,0 9.20654296875,50.00086069107056,0 7.010795159396929,51.45182674763414,0</coordinates>

Comment: At present i have 2 list. 1st list has all the latitude values and other list with longitude values. Now i need organize the latitude and longitude values as per KML format.

Comment: But in your example the output is `11.65148,48.2490,0 11.6515,48.2490,0 11.6516,48.2491,0` where you have zeros that you have not in your two original lists as well as some spaces that is not obvious where they go from.

Comment: Yeah zeros are not in the list. But i need to add it additionally with a space so that it matches with KML format else google earth cannot track the latitude and longitude values.

Comment: See update. There is a bit more code to format output in the required way.

Comment: I wrote a simple hardcoded code which worked.     String listString = "";
  int j = 0;

  for (Double s : mergeList) {
   if (j > 0) {
    if (j % 2 == 0) {

     listString = listString + "0 ";
    }
   }

   listString = listString + s + ",";
   j++;
  }
  listString = listString + "0";